# Encryption Strength of a Base64 Expanded Key

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm using AES to encrypt some data and I noticed a bug in the code that causes the Base64 encoded key to be used instead of the raw bytes. The key itself was 16 bytes and the Base64 encoded version is 24 bytes. I'm curious as to what impact this has on the security of the actual data. The encryption function would use AES-192 instead of AES-128 because of the key length but obviously the randomness of the key is less especially considering the end padding.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing the bug? What language is it in? In most cases it should be pretty hard to accidentally pass a UTF16 string where a `byte[]` is required.

Comment: I'm using erlang/elixir so I'm passing a binary to the block_encrypt call. I've verified that it accepts both the raw data as well as the base64 encoded version.

Comment: And how is the base64 encoded version stored? If it is a string it has to be character encoded. Is it an 8-bit encoding scheme like ASCII? Or something else? This bug would probably cause a predictable loss of entropy and render the encrypted data far easier to crack.

Comment: Yes, just ASCII. I know there will be a drop in the security I'm just curious how bad it is.

Comment: "How bad it is" depends on the implementation. It is not likely it will detect the length of the base64 and increase the bits to 192; if it is expecting a byte array, it won't know to look for a null terminator or anything of that kind.

Comment: This question is off-topic here and should be asked instead in [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Almost certainly you will not lose any security over AES-128 if your base64 key contains a full 128 bits of entropy. You'll get 128 bits of security obviously, not 192.

Comment: As James commented, if your key is really random (!), you will get AES-192 algorithm with 128 bit key security, which should be still enough.